# How to get Tapestry 5.3.8 and Wildfly 10 to redirect to the index.tml home page

Tags: java-8, wildfly, tapestry

I'm having trouble finding in the documentation for Wildfly how to get Tapestry to redirect to my Index.tml page. This file is located in the root of my war file. However, when I try to access my localhost I get a blank page that only says "Not Found".

Has anyone run into a similar problem when switching from Tomcat to Wildfly and how did you get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the correct context name? Check the logs to verify the context name.

Comment: if you access Index.tml directly does it work? Also how do you have welcome file list configured in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "problem" to make tapestry working on jboss (wildfly is a jboss starting from version 8). The point is tapestry uses own classloader to support update classes on fly but it can't find own classes in jboss/wildfly.

check out https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/HowToRunTapestry5OnJBoss7Dot1 , if Wildfly is not changed too much from last jboss version then it could work.
If not then it could be a good starting point in looking solution. 
Good luck.

P.S: Also http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowTos could help.

P.P.S.: for case if code in wiki is broken you can use mine version of the class
 codeshare.io/EqbZg (do not have reputation to post more then two links)

Answer (score 0):

The index.tml should not live in the package "com.example.app.pages", depending on what you specified in the web.xml (tapestry.app-package)